# Run Cron job every N minutes plus offset

Tags: cron

`*/20 * * * *`

Ensures it runs every 20 minutes, I'd like to run a task every 20 minutes, starting at 5 past the hour, is this possible with Cron?  Would it be:

`5/20 * * * *`  ?

Comment: Thanks the Babylonians, who decided that our time system should be exactly divided by 1,2,3,4,5 and 6.

Answer (score 707, accepted):

To run a task every 20 minutes starting at 5 past the hour, try this:

```
 5-59/20 * * * *
```

**Explanation**

An `*` in the minute field is the same as `0-59/1` where `0-59` is the *range* and `1` is the *step*. The command will run at the first minute in the *range* (0), then at all successive minutes that are distant from the first by *step* (1), until the last (59).

Which is why `*/20 * * * *` will run at 0 minutes, 20 minutes after, and 40 minutes after -- which is the same as every 20 minutes. However, `*/25 * * * *` will run at 0 minutes, 25 minutes after, and 50 minutes after -- which is not the same as every 25 minutes. That's why it's usually desirable to use a step value in the minute field that divides evenly into 60.

So to offset the start time, specify the range explicitly and set the first value to the amount of the offset.

**Examples**

`5-59/20 * * * *` will run at 5 minutes after, 25 minutes after, and 45 minutes after.

`10-59/25 * * * *` will run at 10 minutes after and 35 minutes after.

`1-59/2 * * * *` will run every odd minute.

Comment: that works perfectly.  How did you find that out?  Can you point me towards the docs?  Thanks.

Comment: A variety of Google searches led me to [this Server Fault answer](http://serverfault.com/a/429397/181709). It had a mistake which had me really confused, especially since other results suggested that *minutes modulus step should equal zero*. I finally found [this manual page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0054381.html) which gave me the answer. As a result, I was able to comment on the Server Fault answer which has now been fixed. I don't remember the actual search terms I used to find the IBM page.

Comment: Thanks and very good work @toxalot, I wish we could award you the "Tireless Investigator" badge! :P

Comment: LOL. I needed to run a job every 10 minutes (offset by 5) and really did not want to use a comma delimited list, so I was determined to find the answer.

Comment: Is it possible to do an offset in seconds?  Run every 5 minutes + 10 seconds?

Comment: CPanel doesn't seem to like this unfortunately :(

Comment: With this expression 0 57-59/15 * 1/1 * ? , the job will only start once (00:57) in an hour and not four times like I want it to (00:57,01:12,01:27,01:42). I want the user to be able to start the job every 15 minutes starting at a specific minute like in this case an offset of 57 minutes but the job will only execute within the range of 57-59 using your solution. The solution I found is the following : When the offset is greater than the step, I subtract the offset by the quotient of (Offset / Step) * step. In this case : 57 / 15 = 3, 3*15=45, so 57-45=12. The cron will be 0 12/15.

Comment: @BobbyS There's just the hacky way suggested by LeoChu's answer, which is to add `sleep 10;` to the beginning of your command.

Comment: I've written a bit on top of this to illustrate some more patterns https://gist.github.com/timkpaine/09386bb62673d0fd38a76856a1dcb8e3

Comment: Here's a useful website to test various settings: https://crontab.guru/

Comment: Linked docs no longer exist. But `man 5 crontab` is what you want, e.g.: https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab

Comment: I am impressed at @toxalot's mad google skillz and I am flabbergasted by the stupidness of the cron system.
If you have the chance (I guess that means runit instead of systemd), use [snooze](https://github.com/leahneukirchen/snooze).

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me on my scheduler. It says cron expression is invalid required 6 fields but found 5.

Answer (score 89):

Sure!

```
5,25,45 * * * * /your/cron
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had ended up doing this, was hoping there might be a more elegant solution to it.

Comment: Sometimes the simple solution is better because it's easy easy to read and understand.  I like knowing that `5-59/20` is possible, but `5,25,45` has the advantage that it's immediately very clear what that does.

Comment: only if your step is big enough

Comment: This is a much better example. It takes 0 cognitive load to understand when the job kicks off.

Answer (score 19):

You can try: `*/5 * * * * sleep N; your job`

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this - in fact this is very similar to how certbot's cron job achieves a random offset which helps keep server load balanced. sure doesn't deserve all those downvotes

Comment: This made me wonder how to sleep a random number of seconds.  
`sleep \`shuf -i 1-100 -n 1\`` does the trick.

Comment: dammit, @Laizer you made me learn something again! (thank you!)