# Starting a cron job at 30 minutes in Unix

Tags: unix, cron, jobs

I want to run a cron job for every 2 minutes from 9:30 to 12.How should I do it?

Is this correct? Where should I add 30?

```
*/2  9-12   *   *   *
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786410/run-cron-job-every-n-minutes-plus-offset

Comment: it is a bit unclear which times you want the job to run: 9.30, 10, 10.30, 11, 11.30 and 12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll actually need two cronjobs. Add `30-59` in the place of the first asterisk, for execution from 9:30 until 10: `30-59/2 9 * * *`.
And then a second one for execution from 10:00 until 12:00 `*/2 10-12 * * *`

Easy tool to check: [http://cronchecker.net/check?statement=30-59%2F2+9-12+*+*+*+echo+yep](http://cronchecker.net/check?statement=30-59%2F2%209-12%20*%20*%20*%20echo%20yep)
So the whole thing will be something like:

```
30-59/2 9 * * * echo yep
*/2 10-12 * * * echo yep
```