# java Quartz Scheduler cron expression for every after 30 minutes quarter past the hours

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I know how to run a job at every 30 minutes is by using following cron expression:

```
0 0/30 * * * ?
```

It runs the job at every 30 minutes like ::

```
10:30, 11, 11:30, 12.
```

I want to make it run every after 30 minutes quarter past the hours like::

```
10:15, 10:45, 11:15, 11:45.
```

How do I make it run every after 30 minutes quarter past the hours as explained above?

UPDATE :: I have seen that link. The solution stated in the given link is not working. It started cron job at quarter past hour but It is running on every second of the minute like 15:15:00, 15:15:01, 15:15:02.....

Thanks

Comment: do you need the job to start/end at a specific time / only run on specific days etc?

Comment: not at any specific time/day... just like i have mentioned .. all days .. Just want to run it like 10:45, 11:15.........instead of 10:30, 11.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Cron job every N minutes plus offset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786410/run-cron-job-every-n-minutes-plus-offset)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just give it a minute value of `15,45`

as in

```
0 15,45 * * * ? *
```

see www.cronmaker.com

Comment: Thanks but It gives RunTimeException as : 

        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: CronExpression '* 15,45 * * * * ?' is invalid.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: It started cron job at quarter past hour but It is running on every second of the minute like 15:15:00, 15:15:01, 15:15:02.....

Comment: How can that be, the first `column` is `0` being seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,15 means start time:

```
0 15/30 * * * ?
```

Comment: It started cron job at quarter past hour but It is running on every second of the minute like 15:15:00, 15:15:01, 15:15:02.....

Answer (score 1):

Another variant of the answers already provided is:

```
0 15-45/30 * * * ?
```

Which when tested with [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/) gave me the below results (Note the different start times):

[image]
[image]

As you've had some issues with the other cron expressions, I scheduled a job with the above and it has been running fine