# Cron Expression for every 30 minutes in quarter hour periods?

Tags: cron, cron-task

I am currently trying to generate a cron expression that runs every 30 minutes throughout the day but at hours like 10:15, 10:45, 11:15 and so on. I know that the cron expression `0 0/30 * 1/1 * ? *` runs every 30 minutes but it does it at 10:00, 10:30, 11:00, 11:30 and so on. I wanted to know if there is a way to create a cron expression that would run at hours like 9:15, 9:45, 10:15, 10:45 and so on, like in quarter hour periods?

Comment: Try replacing `0/30` with `15,45` (no space after comma).  This will run 15 and 45 minutes after every hour.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Cron job every N minutes plus offset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786410/run-cron-job-every-n-minutes-plus-offset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running every 30 minutes starting with 15 minutes after the hour is just running twice an hour - at :15 and at :45. So instead of over-complicating, just have list those two options with a comma:

```
0 15,45 * 1/1 * ? *
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

`0 0/30 * 1/1 * ? *`

Use:

`0 15,45 * 1/1 * ? *`

This will run 15 and 45 minutes after every hour, resulting in the desired times 9:15, 9:45, 10:15, 10:45, etc.