# jenkins cron: run every 3rd minute, starting at 1

Tags: jenkins, cron

I want to set Jenkins to run a job every 3rd minute, but not starting at 0.  Basically, I have 3 jobs and I want to cycle through them each minute.

The first job I can run every 3rd minute with `*/3 * * * *`.  But the second I tried `1/3 * * * *` and it failed with `hudson.remoting.ProxyException: line 1:2: unexpected token: /`

How do I write this expression?

Comment: I believe the problem here is in Jenkins evaluation of cron expression. I am using

0 0/12 * * *

to run every day at Noon and Midnight, but am getting the same error the OP is:

"unexpected token: /"

Comment: @timblaktu - It looks like Jenkins is sticking close to the [gnu mcron](https://www.gnu.org/software/mcron/manual/html_node/Crontab-file.html#Crontab-file) (and by implication vixie cron) standard, which has the `x-y/z` and `*/z` but doesn't specify `x/z`. (The [IEEE standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/crontab.html) doesn't even allow for the `/` construct at all, just comma-separated lists.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

- job 1: `0-57/3 * * * *`
- job 2: `1-58/3 * * * *`
- job 3: `2-59/3 * * * *`

Think of the cron minute entry as meaning "range/step" (or, "run this every *step* minutes over the minute range *start*-*end*)

**Reference:** I was able to figure it out from this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19204734), which includes some helpful related links and a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: Then why does cron.help or other cron docs show that */3, 1/3, etc are all valid cron expressions? 

I believe the problem here is in Jenkins evaluation of cron expression. I am using:

0 0/12 * * *

to run every day at Noon and Midnight, but am getting the same error the OP is:

"unexpected token: /"