# Is there any simpler way to write the cron job for every 5 minutes starting from 4th min then 9th min and so on

Tags: node.js, cron

I am trying to write cron job for every 5 minutes, starting from 4th minute, 9th, 14th, and so on...

```
const cron = require("node-cron"); 
cron.schedule(`4,9,14,19,24,29,34,39,44,49,54,59 * * * *`, async function() { 
    console.log('scheduleCron ',new Date());
    // my function call
})
```

It is executing perfectly, but I want to know is this the only method to do like this or any other method?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why the `javascript` tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Run Cron job every N minutes plus offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786410/run-cron-job-every-n-minutes-plus-offset)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run Cron job every N minutes plus offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786410/run-cron-job-every-n-minutes-plus-offset)

Answer (score 1):

> “At every 5th minute from 4 through 59.”

```
4/5 * * * *
```

[Crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/#4/5_*_*_*_*)

**Warning**: *Non standard! May not work with every cron.*